# Need day of week as string (Sunday, Monday ...) in Queryable where clause

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, dynamic-linq

I need to check whether the provided keyword is present in the day-name of a date in the db. I have done it by using dynamic query.

```
ArrayList paramList = new ArrayList();
int paramCount = 0;
StringBuilder queryString = new StringBuilder();

if (keyword != null)
{
    queryString.Append(" and ClosureDate.Value.DayOfWeek.ToString().ToUpper().Contains(@" + paramCount + ")");
    paramList.Add(this.Keyword.ToUpper());
    paramCount++;
}
var abc= _context.ABC.Where(t => t.RecordStatus == 1).Select(t => t).OrderByDescending(t => t.Created).AsQueryable();
abc= abc.AsQueryable().Where(queryString[0].ToString(), searchArgs.ToArray());
```

This ToString() here is creating problem. I tried in other ways but, no luck. Can anyone help on it?

Comment: In SQL Server, you can use DATENAME()  For example Select datename(weekday,getdate())

Answer (score 0):

You can write your SQL Query as below.

```
    DECLARE @Dates TABLE
(
  ProductID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
  Dates DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO @Dates (Dates)
VALUES (GETDATE())
      ,(GETDATE()-1)
      ,(GETDATE()-2)
      ,(GETDATE()-3)
      ,(GETDATE()-4)
      ,(GETDATE()-5)

SELECT Dates 
FROM @Dates

SELECT Dates,DATENAME(WEEKDAY,Dates) AS DayOfWeek
FROM @Dates
```

Then in C#/MVC/ASP.Net App use the something like  .Where(t => t.DayOfWeek.Contains("Monday"))  to filter the result set.